# Twilio Programmable chat channel Get Last Message not returning any response

Tags: chat, twilio

I'm attempting to retrieve 10 last messages from the TCHChannel object that I have by calling the following.

```
[channel.messages getLastMessagesWithCount:10 completion:^(TCHResult *result, NSArray<TCHMessage *> *messages)
{
    NSLog(@"Messages");
}];
```

But it doesn't seem to be returning any response, the completion block isn't even being triggered.

I'm sure there are at least 3 messages because I got 3 as a response for 'count' in this method call:

```
[channel getMessagesCountWithCompletion:^(TCHResult *result, NSUInteger count) {
    NSLog(@"Number of messages: %lu", (long)count);
}];
```

Am I missing something? I've looked through the example and I'm sure I initiated the client correctly. (works, I can retrieve my channels etc) Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my own mistake.

I needed to set TCHClientSynchronizationStrategyAll to the TwilioChatClientProperties object before initialising the chat client.

This allows me to retrieve everything regarding all channels, unlike the TCHClientSynchronizationStrategyChannelList, which gives me only the metadata.